C standard difference between int_least32_t and long
I was wondering, what is the difference between int_least32_t and long, since according to the standard, long has to be at least 32 bits wide and int_least32_t should, according to the standard, also be at least 32 bits wide, therefore equivalent in definition to long.
That brings me to the question, what is the difference between them (if we are considering the case of an implementation which is also equipped with C standard library)?
Sources - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types.

I would expect int_least32_t to be an alias for int, not long, on modern hardware/OS setups.

True, but in general, [int]>=16, while [long]>=32 (which therefore matches int_least32_t), but, of course, it could also be [int]==[long]==32, or, as it is on my system, [int]==32, [long]==[long long]==64.

Unless you're working with low end embedded stuff or into retro computing or other esoteric platforms, int is going to be 32 bits.

@Shawn I can't argue about that.

long must be at least 32 bits wide, but it is allowed to be larger even if a 32 bit type exists on the architecture.
int_least32_t must be 32 bits wide if such a type exists on the architecture, and can only be larger if that's impossible on a given architecture (and must then be the next smallest size available).

int_least32_t will be a typedef for the the smallest integer type capable of holding a 32 bit value.
long is at least 32 bits but is often 64 bits, depending on the platform.

Useful cite:

The typedef name int_leastN_t designates a signed integer type with a width of at least N, such that no signed integer type with lesser size has at least the specified width. Thus, int_least32_t denotes a signed integer type with a width of at least 32 bits.
C2x § 7.22.1.2 1

int_least32_t is the narrowest, yet at least 32-bit.  As CHAR_BIT == 8is very common, this means int_least32_t is 32-bit -possible the same rank as long or even int.  int_least32_t is really only useful for high portability code that might deal with rare platforms of CHAR_BIT == 9, 10, 12,... non-power-of-2 or where CHAR_BIT > 32.  Otherwise use ìnt32_t.
long is at least 32 bit, as LONG_MAX is at least 2,147,483,647, but may be larger like 64-bit.  Both cases are common these days.

int_least32_t is also useful on setups like old Crays where all data types are 64 bit, and unlike int32_t, it's guaranteed to exist, so unless you need exactly 32 bits for precise masking or the like, arguably, int_least32_t should be the default over int32_t for maximum portability (at the expense of annoying verbosity).

@ShadowRanger Answer updated.

Just out of curiosity, on what (modern) platform (therefore not stuff like old PDPs, Crays and so on, but something modern/actively used) is CHAR_BIT != 8, and to be specific, on what (modern) platform is CHAR_BIT not aligned to a power of 2? And how is a byte implemented then on such a platform (also, why would you ever design nowadays a platform not having CHAR_BIT aligned to power of 2?)?

@luksev Many questions in your comment worthy or a post on some stack exchange site.  Consider posting there as they are too deep for a complete comment exchange.
Note that in C, a byte is not certainly 8-bits even if such implementation are rare or archaic.  I suspect some graphics processors may (or might) use CHAR_BIT == 64.  They have in the past.

@chux-ReinstateMonica than you for the advice, I will see what I can do about it.
